# Wordpress admin page not found error

Tags: wp-admin, urls

I accidentally changed my wordpress website url from what it was to the url which is same as my site url and after then I am not able to login into my admin it shows error of page not found(while using my original wordpress site url) and if I try to login through my site url it shows me redirected you too many times.

Please help me!
I tried accesing file through ftp but got no luck in that, also tried to go to wp-login.php but in that also page not found error is coming.
and also tried deleting cookies.Tried disabling plugins and themes from filezilla but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have database access for some reason, you can also use

```
// use these in your wp-config.php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

or

```
// use these in your functions.php
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

to regain access to your site. You can read more about changing the site urls from the codex, [Changing The Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Answer (score 0):

I you accidentally changed the site url you can change it back manually, via your database manager (usually phpmyadmin): look at the `wp_options` table and search for `home` and `siteurl` options and edit them back to the original value (your website url).